# photoshop CS3 working on windows 10

Tags: adobe-photoshop, windows-10-upgrade

not sure if it is an appropriate  post if not feel free to tell me and I will delete it but I can't find any other resources that answers that...does anyone know if photoshop CS3 will work after i upgrade to windows 10? any info is appreciated

Comment: After you upgrade to windows 10 you have 30 days to roll back...

Comment: If it worked on Windows 7, Windows 8, or Windows 8.1 then it will work on Windows 10.  You can also create a virtual machine, install Windows 10 and CS3, and test the compatibility before you upgrade the host OS.  Microsoft provides virtual machines for similar testing purposes on their website.

Comment: @Ramhound thank you! I am currently running 7 and it works fine. I am aware of the VM just don't want to get into all that lol too much hassle thanks

Comment: @Dave that is awesome I did not know you can roll back. Microsoft is stepping their game up I see.

Comment: I actually would recommend @ramhound suggestion first,  it would possibly be less hassle and I would imagine much faster 

Comment: @Dave it is not, as this is particular to adobe products. not all software react the same way to the upgrade

Comment: Are you saying the answer in that post doesn't solve your issue?